# Recursive CTE on every row in a stored procedure with parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure, recursive-cte

I have a table called AccountNode.
Where the the column nodeId has a parent in the ParentNodeId col.

```
AccountNode
nodeId   | ParentNodeId  |  Flag | SetId | 

1           2              N     1 
2           115            N     1 
115         4              N     1
4           5              Y     1
12          13             N     1 
13          14             N     1 
14          15             Y     1 
23          24             N     1 
25          30             Y     1
```

**What i need** :
i need to get the parent node of each node id  where the flag is Y (this is where we need to stop our recursive cte), **for the setId passed as parameter to the procedure.**

```
eg : 
input: 
for set_id : 1 
output: 

nodeId    parentNode  flag    set_id
1           5           Y        1 
12          15          Y        1 
25          30          Y        1
```

i have written a recursive cte  to get the parent node for a node id , **but i am having trouble wrting it for a setid where
, i need to loop through all the nodeIds in a setid , to get the parentNode**.
Here is my sql :

```
with accountNode_cte  (nodeId, parentNode, flag, set_id) as 
(select nodeId , parentNode, flag, set_id) from accountNode where nodeId = '1' 
union all
select accountNode.nodeId, accountNode.parentNode, accountNode.flag, accountNode.set_id from 
accountNode 
join accountNode_cte on accountNode.nodeId = accountNode_cte.parentNode
and accountNode_cte.flag !='Y')
select * from accountNode_cte where flag='Y'
```

i am pretty new to writing sql procedures , not sure how to go about this

Comment: Once you have the query working, where does the PL/SQL procedure come in?

Comment: This query gives correct result for a nodeId. Was stuck when when a setId comes into picture which has multiple nodeIds under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse the node hierarchy from the starting nodes, remember starting point, track level, take max within starting point level rows.

```
with accountNode_cte(p, l, nodeId, parentNode, flag, set_id) as (
  select parentNodeId p, 1 l, nodeId , parentNodeId, flag, set_id 
  from accountNode 
  where flag = 'Y' and set_id = 1
  
  union all
  
  select p, l+1, accountNode.nodeId, accountNode.parentNodeId, accountNode.flag, accountNode.set_id 
  from accountNode 
  join accountNode_cte on accountNode.parentnodeId = accountNode_cte.NodeId
)
select distinct first_value(nodeId) over(partition by p order by l desc) nodeId, p parentnId
from accountNode_cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8dca2d619c2bf93caa8bdf3ebf8e42e)